# Materialize ScrollSpy options not working with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I have a `React` (16.8) project setup with `materialze` and I try to custom `scrollSpy` which is randomly working. Sometimes it does have an offset of 0, sometimes the default behaviour kicks in (center of the screen).

```
import ...
import M from 'materialize-css';

const Product = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollspy');
      M.ScrollSpy.init(elems, { scrollOffset: 0 });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <a href="#certified" className="product-anchor-link">
      certified
    <a>
    ...
    <div className="certified-wrapper scrollspy" id="certified">
    ...
    <div>
  );
};
```

I also use `Hooks` so I can proceed with a stateless component which is important for the project.

Any ideas what I did wrong? Unfortunately there is very little to find about `materialze` issues in general on the internet ...

Comment: The main problem I see here is that scrollspy isn't written with React in mind. And since React will add and remove DOM elements all the time, that fact will most likely break most of these libraries.

Comment: @Chris G, I had a feeling that this might be the problem. Thanks for confirming, I guess I will have to do it myself or go with a npm package ...

Answer (score 0):

The below works just fine with useEffect. You shouldn't need to add a listener on DOMContentLoaded. Below works fine when within a parent-most component.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".scrollspy");
  M.ScrollSpy.init(elems, { scrollOffset: 0 });
}, []);
```